# Finding stray IBOutlets

Tags: xcode, iboutlet

Is there a good way to detect stray IBOutlets prior to running?

Like if I added this code:

```
@interface MyViewController()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *magicView;
@end
```

Then I connected it in Interface Builder. Some time later, I remove the outlet but forget to remove it in, say, my iPad storyboard. When I run the app, it'll crash with a KVO error at runtime.

IB shows a warning on them, but you need to click each view controller and search for yellow exclamation points. I'd rather just see a list, compiler warnings, something more prominent.

Answer (score 0):

Interface Builder saves to XML files that can be examined in with a text editor in an effort to find zombie connections.